# replace commas with spaces from json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a looping function creating:

```
<li id="id1" name="Tag1,Tag2,Tag3">
<li id="id2" name="Tag1,Tag2,Tag3">


$.each(data.posts, function(i, post){       
 $('<li >', {id: this.id , name: post.tags})  
});
```

How do I replace the commas between the tags with spaces.
Also is there a way I can send the tags to a "class" attribute instead of "name". It seems to not work in Safari.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you probably want is this:

```
$('<li >', {id: this.id , className : post.tags.join(' ')})
```

By default, when you cast an array to a string, it get concatenated with commas as you have seen. Using `join()` will solve the problem.

Also, `class` is a reserved keyword in all browsers *(though some won't throw an error if you use it)*, so the attribute you should use for setting the class is called `className`

Comment: +1, `class` is a [future reserved word](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.5.3) all of them should be avoided as identifiers...

Comment: The above assumes tags is an array (which, apparently it is in Alex's case).  If tags is a string, you would could do either "tags.split(',').join(' ')" or "tags.replace(/,/g, ' ')"

Comment: You can do 'class' as the key as well, with quotes

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.each(data.posts, function(i, post){ 
 $('<li >', {id: this.id , name: post.tags.join(' ')});  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data.posts, function(i, post) {
    $('<li >', {id: this.id , name: post.tags.replace(/[,]/g, ' ')})
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the replace string method (as mentioned in other replies) to replace the commas.

As for the classes, add them like this:

```
$('<li >', {id: this.id }).addClass(post.tags.join(' '));
```

Comment: This will only replace the first ','.  To replace all, you need to pass a regex with the 'g' option set as the first arg, as in my comment above. (And, of course, this also assumes tag is a String, not an Array)

Comment: oops, I hadn't actually looked at that part, as mentioned, I copied the code from above. The addClass is the correct way to add classes, as opposed to a "className" attribute, which is what I was demonstrating.

I have adjusted the code to properly concat the tags, sorry about that.